# Developing task switcher, code changes not reflected on Alt+Tab

Tags: qml, kde-plasma

I'm developing my own task switcher in QML. When I change the code (`main.qml`) and press Alt+Tab, the KDE task switcher stays the same even if its preview from the System Settings shows the changes. The task switcher gets updated only after the next login.

I use Kubuntu 22.10, KDE 5.26.5 and my Task switcher is in `~/.local/share/kwin/tabbox/` folder.

Is there a way to apply QML code changes or to notify KDE about the source code being modified? Or is there another way to develop a task switcher (not invoking it by Alt+Tab)?

I tried removing qmlcache `rm -rf ~/.cache/*qmlcache*`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting KWin should work: `kwin_x11 --replace` (if you're on X11; afaik it's not possible to restart the window manager on Wayland).

You can also try `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin org.kde.KWin.reconfigure`.

Comment: I'm on X11, so `kwin_x11 --replace` worked. Thanks. The dbus call didn't work, unfortunatelly, since it's closer to what I hoped for :-) Reloading the whole kwin is a bit large hammer, but better than logging out and in.